# How to detect an appropriate return type of a template function in a straightforward way while manually coding

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, boost

My old project is still using the VS2008 which cannot support c++11. Whereas it uses boost_1_43_0. I wrote the following code, then I replace duplicate function calls with a temporary variable and only one function call, but I cannot easily to determine the return type of the function [`is_any_of`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost/algorithm/is_any_of.html) (no `auto` of c++11, [C++ compiler support (Updated Link)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support#C.2B.2B_2011_features) )

How I can get a straightforward way to define such a variable?

```
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/trim.hpp>
// #include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
// #include <boost/algorithm/string/classification.hpp>
// #include <boost/algorithm/string/predicate.hpp>


std::wstring wsExtraHeaders(L"X-Forwarded-For, X-Requested-With, X-UA-Compatible,   X-Powered-By, ");
std::set<std::wstring> extraHeaderKeys;

// Old code

boost::algorithm::trim_if(wsExtraHeaders, boost::is_any_of(L",\t "));
boost::algorithm::split(extraHeaderKeys, wsExtraHeaders, boost::is_any_of(L",\t "), boost::token_compress_on);

// New code

boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<wchar_t> delemiterPred = boost::is_any_of(L",\t "); // here, determine the return type
boost::algorithm::trim_if(wsExtraHeaders, delemiterPred);
boost::algorithm::split(extraHeaderKeys, wsExtraHeaders, delemiterPred, boost::token_compress_on);

// C++11, but `auto` cannot be used in VS2008
// auto delemiterPred = boost::is_any_of(L",\t ");
```

The implemention of the function `is_any_of`:

```
//! is_any_of predicate
/*!
    Construct the \c is_any_of predicate. The predicate holds if the input
    is included in the specified set of characters.

    \param Set A set of characters to be recognized
    \return An instance of the \c is_any_of predicate 
*/
template<typename RangeT>
inline detail::is_any_ofF<
    BOOST_STRING_TYPENAME range_value<RangeT>::type> 
is_any_of( const RangeT& Set )
{
    iterator_range<BOOST_STRING_TYPENAME range_const_iterator<RangeT>::type> lit_set(boost::as_literal(Set));
    return detail::is_any_ofF<BOOST_STRING_TYPENAME range_value<RangeT>::type>(lit_set); 
}
```

**---Updated**

VS2008 and VS2013 IDE tooltip

It can be detected by vs2013 IDE for @Angew option 2.

[image: VS2008 vs VS2013 IDE tooltip]

Comment: "is it a good idea to..." == opinion-based question.

Comment: :) I make they consistent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you cannot use `auto` (which would of course be the best thing for this), I can see two options for you, each with its own drawback:

1. Abstract away the exact type into a more generic, but expressable type. For a predicate like this, it seems the correct type would be:

   ```
   boost::function<bool(wchar_t)> delemiterPred = boost::is_any_of(L",\t ");
   ```

   The drawback is that you might now be paying (some) runtime performance for the type erasure inside `boost::function`. Of course, the question is whether this particular little bit of code is a bottleneck in your app.
2. Reach into Boost's implementation and copy & paste the exact return type from the definition of `boost::is_any_of`. The drawback is that this can break when you upgrade to a different Boost version which might have a different return type.

It's up to you to decide which of these drawbacks is more acceptable for you. Unless performance profiling on real data told me otherwise, I'd go with option 1 for maintainability reasons.

Comment: Good point! I don't seem to find the drawback of  option 1 :)